# Default browser is Google Hangouts

Tags: system-settings, default-browser, google-hangouts

My default browser is  Google Hangouts and I want to change it to Chrome.

[image]

default browser setting
[image: default browser setting]

Comment: I'm not aware of any Google Hangouts client for Linux. Hangouts work right in the browser. I can't see any sign of Google Hangouts set as default browser.

Comment: You have firefox listed as default.  To change to chrome just click on down arrow beside firefox and choose/click chrome.

Comment: @crip659 chrome is not listed. and chrome is installed

Comment: Did you install chrome separately(by itself) or did you install google hangouts and chrome was included?  Would try to install Chrome deb, might have to uninstall chrome and hangouts first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone. It has been resolved.

Go to home directory. press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> - it will show all the hidden files. Go to the .`local/share/applications` directory and delete mime files. Restart the computer. Check the result.

Answer (score 2):

As @Kulfy mostly correctly pointed out, there's no NATIVE (but it can be installed) Google Hangouts client. From your screenshot, it lists Firefox very clearly as the default web browser. I suspect there was an issue with the version of Chrome you installed, although I don't see how that would happen. Try reinstalling chrome, making sure to use the latest STABLE release. If that doesn't fix it, try rebooting and see what happens.